# How to create a non-static list from JSON parse in java?

Tags: java, http, parsing, static, request

I'm still relatively new to Java and have hit a problem in the project I'm currently working on.  I'm trying to get data from UN Comtrade via an HTTP request and then to parse this into an ArrayList.

I've managed to do that with the code below, but what I would then like to do is create an additional 'getList' method in this class so that I can call the list from other parts of the program.

However, I can't figure out how to do this as the parse method is static and so the list that it creates is unaccessible.  Can anyone help me out with this?

My main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        ReporterArea reporterArea = new ReporterArea();
        reporterArea.fetchReporterArea();
    
    }
```

The reporter area class:

```
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class ReporterArea {
    
    public void fetchReporterArea(){
        
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create("https://comtrade.un.org/api/get?max=500&type=C&freq=A&px=HS&ps=2016&r=all&p=0&rg=2&cc=TOTAL")).build();
        client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
                .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
                .thenApply(ReporterArea::parse)
                .join();
    }
    
    public static String parse(String dataset){
        
        JSONObject countries = new JSONObject(dataset);
        
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONArray array = countries.getJSONArray("dataset");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
            String combined = array.getJSONObject(i).optString("rtTitle") + "; " + array.getJSONObject(i).optString("rtCode");
            list.add(combined);
         } 
        
        for (String i : list){
            System.out.println(i);
           
        } 
        
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, since you're already using an instance of `ReporterArea` why is `parse()` static at all? Besides that, the implementations of both methods don't require them to be instance methods but in that case you might then want to return an object that contains the data (e.g. the list) and pass it around to other code. _Do not_ make the list itself or the variable referencing the instance of `ReporterArea` static as this will cause further problems down the line.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your response - as I mentioned below, I can't get the HTTP request to work when the parse method is static

Comment: generate 1 static list, private static List<String> dataList; make the setter syncronized. in the parse method, call the setter of datalist with the HTTP response

Comment: But _why_ is the parse method static? There's no need for that which I could see. Also: why are you only returning `null` from that method? What is the return value meant to be? Why not return the list instead?

Comment: Btw, if `parse()` were not static you'd use it like `.thenApply(this::parse)` (you're in the instance already) or `thenApply(e->this.parse(e))` (`this` could be replaced with a reference to any other instance in you case).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the api logic you can just create a private List myList variable and after the for block that adds elements to the list in the static method, write

```
private static List<String> myList; //edit added static keyword after OP's comment

for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
     String combined = array.getJSONObject(i).optString("rtTitle") + "; " + array.getJSONObject(i).optString("rtCode");
     list.add(combined);
} 
myList = new ArrayList<>(list);
```

After that you can create a public getter method like this:

```
public List<String> getList(){
    if(myList !=null) {
       return myList;
    } else {
       return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

you have to be careful and be sure that the getList() method is called after the parse

Comment: Thanks for your response - the problem is though that the parse method is static so I can't reference non-static variables in it.  I've tried making parse non-static but this breaks the code when I run the main program

Comment: Yes Sorry, my bad. It will work if you define the variable as private static List<String> myList

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the list of the parsed strings you should just return it from the `parse` method, and it can be static because it does not depend on any instance data as mentioned above.

Then you may also want to refactor `fetchReporterArea` to return `CompletableFuture<List<String>>` if you really need to retrieve the data asynchronously.

```java
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class ReporterArea {

    public CompletableFuture<List<String>> fetchReporterArea() {

        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(
                        "https://comtrade.un.org/api/get?max=500&type=C&freq=A&px=HS&ps=2016&r=all&p=0&rg=2&cc=TOTAL"))
                .build();
        return client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
                .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
                .thenApply(ReporterArea::parse);
    }

    public static List<String> parse(String dataset) {

        JSONObject countries = new JSONObject(dataset);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONArray array = countries.getJSONArray("dataset");

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
            
            list.add(row.optString("rtTitle") + "; " + row.optString("rtCode"));
        }
        
        return list;
    }
}
```

Then method `main` should be updated as follows:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
         ReporterArea reporterArea = new ReporterArea();
         CompletableFuture<List<String>> asyncResult = reporterArea.fetchReporterArea();
         
         asyncResult.get().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

**Output** (abbreviated)

```
Albania; 8
Algeria; 12
Andorra; 20
Angola; 24
...
```